# MySQL (6TB Data) Server Hick Ups

Tags: mysql, database, percona

We have a MySQL Setup running Percona 5.7 (5.7.12-5-1.trusty) (36 cores, 768 GB Memory, 3.5 TB Raid-10 of 8 SSDs). 
DB size is around 6 TB, some of the tables are larger then 1TB with billion of records. On average, we have around 12-18.0000 queries per second (about 70% of them are SELECTs).

Also we are using ZFS with lz4 compression and 16k recordsize.

Mysql Master sometimes stop to respond to queries in time and gathers alot of connections and doesnt respond to clients anymore for a minute or so.

In slow query logs we see that all slow queries group in the same 0.1 of second.
For example:

`SELECT time, COUNT(*) FROM slow_query_log WHERE time BETWEEN '2016-08-26 13:16:00' AND '2016-08-26 13:19:00'`

`...
'2016-08-26 13:16:46', '1'
'2016-08-26 13:16:55', '1'
'2016-08-26 13:17:00', '1'
'2016-08-26 13:17:09', '1'
'2016-08-26 13:17:21', '1'
'2016-08-26 13:18:08', '340'
'2016-08-26 13:18:10', '1'
'2016-08-26 13:18:29', '1'
'2016-08-26 13:18:50', '1'
...`

We see the same picture 2 times per hour. What is even more interesting, that all slow queries in that moment have pretty the same query time 15-25 sec, 
even queries like `select @@session.tx_read_only; #17 sec` or `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; #21 sec`. First, we thought that we might have some heave queries, 
but then we've found `select @@session.tx_read_only;` slow queries, which should be executed instantly, and became totally confused.

We see no deadlocks, stuck queries, long running queries, system lock or anything when this happens, nothing in the logfile aswell.

Other configuration parts:

```
innodb_adaptive_hash_index      = OFF
innodb_doublewrite              = OFF
skip-innodb_doublewrite
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 512M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 2
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 400G 
innodb_buffer_pool_instances   = 32 
innodb_write_io_threads        = 64
innodb_read_io_threads         = 64
innodb_flush_neighbors         = 0
innodb_adaptive_hash_index      = OFF
innodb_use_native_aio = 0
performance_schema=off
```

the buffer pool size is on 400gb for a reason. Anytime we raise this as example to 450, or even 650 we get "complete" db freezes for multiple minutes at randomintervals. Also if we accordingly set the correct pool instance values for the higher buffer pool. adaptive_hash_index is off because otherwise
truncate table will completely break the db with freezes aswell but that is a well known bug with adaptive hash index and large buffer pools. native_aio is off
because of ZFS. Performance Schema is off for performance reasons aswell.

iops are ok, no zfs arc issues or anything. cpu utilisation is almost never more then 40% of the available resources. Enough memory free etc.

Anyone got a idea on how to debug this problem?  And yes we know its not ideal to store this much data in mysql ;)

Comment: Do you have a `pt-stalk` capture to share during these issues? There's not much to go on with just the above.